# Submitting the Name of a Particular Button Through a Form

Tags: php, javascript

I have a form that contains several buttons. I want to have the form submit whichever button was clicked (their name attributes will all differ) but since they are all of type submit, I'm not sure how to check which one was clicked. Is there a way to do this? Each button will look like this example:

```
<input class='menuitem' type='submit' value="Bowl of Cheerios" name="5" />
```

Comment: yes I could use that as well, but wouldn't any method of sending that value through POST be the same as sending name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving the button a name means that it will be included in the POST or GET when the user submits the form by clicking on that button.

```
<input type="submit" name="myButton" value="submit button 1 was clicked" />
<input type="submit" name="myButton" value="submit button 2 was clicked" />

<?php echo ($_POST ['myButton']); ?>
```

As the value is taken from the text that's displayed in the button, this can lead to issues regarding internationalization.  A better approach is to give all your submit buttons different names, and check for the presence or absence of particular buttons

```
<input type="submit" name="myButton1" value="submit button 1 was clicked" />
<input type="submit" name="myButton2" value="submit button 2 was clicked" />

<?php echo (isset ($_POST ['myButton1'])? 'Button 1 was clicked': ''); ?>
<?php echo (isset ($_POST ['myButton2'])? 'Button 2 was clicked': ''); ?>
```

One thing you need to keep in mind with this approach is that if the user doesn't click any of the buttons to submit the form then you won't get any value for the submit button in your input at all.  This can happen if the user hits enter in a text input, for example.  You need to handle this case.

Another thing you need to bear in mind is the `<button>` tag.  This tag can be used as a submit button by setting its type to submit, and then it should, according to the specs, behave just like an input type=submit button.  A button can have content richer than a simple input submit, and it can have a value that's independent from its content. The value is what should be posted back to the server when the user clicks the button.

```
<button type="submit" name="myButton" value="1"><img src="button1.png" alt="Button 1" /></button>
<button type="submit" name="myButton" value="2"><img src="button2.png" alt="Button 2" /></button>

<?php echo ($_POST ['mybutton']); ?>
```

or

```
<button type="submit" name="myButton1" value="The value is not relevant in this case"><img src="button1.png" alt="Button 1" /></button>
<button type="submit" name="myButton2" value="The value is not relevant in this case"><img src="button2.png" alt="Button 2" /></button>

<?php echo (isset ($_POST ['myButton1'])? 'Button 1 was clicked': ''); ?>
<?php echo (isset ($_POST ['myButton2'])? 'Button 2 was clicked': ''); ?>
```

However, Internet Explorer 7 fouls this up by submitting the content of the clicked button, instead of the value of the clicked button.

This is a big screwup on IE7's part, but it is at least one you can work around by using the "all submit buttons have different names" techniques.

However, if you're using IE6, things get even worse.  Because when you submit a form with buttons on it, the value of EVERY button gets submitted!  This makes it basically impossible to determine which button a user of IE6 clicked.  Your only recourse in this case is to detect if more than one submit button was submitted with the form, and fail gracefully if it was.

So if you need to support IE6, you can't use the button tag.

Hope this is helpful.